# How to get the variable name in R function

Tags: r

I would like to cite the variable name as a string in a function, but couldn't achieve it.

For example, in one excel, i have 4 worksheets, i need to use the following line 4 times,

```
sales.df<- read_xlsx("abc.xlsx", sheet ="sales")
profit.df<- read_xlsx("abc.xlsx", sheet ="profit")
revenue.df<-read_xlsx("abc.xlsx", sheet ="revenue")
budget.df<- read_xlsx("abc.xlsx", sheet ="budget")
```

Instead, I want to write a function:

```
  read_func = function(sheet_name){

    sheet_name.df<- read_xlsx("abc.xlsx", sheet ="sheet_name"))

    return(sheet_name.df)
 }
```

The call the function

```
    read_func(sales)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The sheet_name is not dynamically updated.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: `"sheet_name"` is a string, it does not change. `sheet_name` is a variable, which a user will set to a string such as `"sales"` or `"profit"`. Use `sheet_name` in side your function, without quotes. And call your function with a string argument, `read_fun("sales")`.

Answer (score 1):

The `readxl` package has a function `excel_sheets()` to read all sheets in a file, which you can use with `lapply` to accomplish the same thing.

```
library(readxl)
lapply(excel_sheets("abc.xlsx"), read_excel, path = "abc.xlsx")
```

It is a part of the tidyverse so you can read more on it [there](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/readxl.pdf).

Comment: Hi Seeellayewhy, This lapply function works fine. But one further question, how could i do the automatically split the list into different data frame, and assign the corresponding name?